# JProfiler: Trying to find memory leak

Tags: jprofiler

My application needs about 10 GByte of RAM for specific input, where for regular inputs roughly 1 GByte is enough. Closer analysis with JProfiler reveals that (after GC) quite a lot of memory is used by standard classes from `java.util.*`:

`LinkedHashMap$Entry`, `HashMap$Entry[]`, `LinkedHashMap`, `HashMap$KeySet`, `HashMap$EntrySet`, `LinkedHashSet`, `TreeMap$Entry`, and `TreeMap` (in this order), and related classes. The following entry is of a class in my own code, where the number of instances and the amount of used memory seems very reasonable.

In detail with a total heap usage of about 900 MByte I see the following `Size` entries in the `All Objects` view:

- `LinkedHashMap$Entry`: 418 MByte
- `HashMap$Entry[]`: 178 MByte
- `LinkedHashMap`: 124 MByte
- `HashMap$KeySet`: 15 MByte

The memory used by `LinkedHashMap` seems to be too high, even when considering that every `LinkedHashSet` is backed by a `LinkedHashMap`.

I recorded object allocation in JProfiler and observe the `Allocation Hot Spots` for `LinkedHashMap`. In there, I see entries that I do not understand:

- The third entry shows a hot spot (with 6.5% of the allocated memory) named `X.<init>` where `X` is a class in my own code. The constructors of this method do not have anything to do with `LinkedHashMap`. Following this entry to `Thread.run` at the end shows a slow decline from 6.5% to 5.8% at `Thread.run`. What could be the problem with my code in `X`? Why is it shown here?
- About 8% of allocated memory is shown in the hot spot named `java.util.HashSet.iterator`. Following this entry along the path with the highest percentage (first entry: 2.8%) I get several methods inside my code until, finally, `java.lang.Thread.run` is shown (with 2.8%). What does this mean? As far as I know the `Thread.run` method does not create instances of `LinkedHashMap`. What is the connection to the `iterator` method?

In general, how do I find the code that keeps references to (a lot of) `LinkedHashMap` objects? Using the Heap Walker I can only see *lots* of those instances, but do not see any pattern (even when observing the paths to the GC roots). In my experiments all instances seem to be in order.

Possibly important things:

- My application constructs a result (for further processing) and, for this construction, the high memory usage is observed. The construction continually creates objects, so waiting for a stable point and then observing every single created `LinkedHashMap` object is not possible.
- I have good computers available to debug (up to 48 cores and 192 GByte of RAM, possibly even more).
- java version "1.7.0_13" (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20), 
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode))
- JProfiler 7.2.2 (Build 7157), licensed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In general, how do I find the code that keeps references to (a lot of) LinkedHashMap objects?

In the heap walker, select "LinkedHashMap" and create a new object set. Then switch to the "References" view and show the **"Cumulated incoming references"**. There, you can analyze references for the entire object set.

[image]

As for your question about the allocation hot spots and why the Thread.run method is shown: These are **back traces**, they show how the hot spot has been invoked and all numbers on the nodes are contributions to the hot spot at the top. The deepest node will already always be an entry point, typically a Thread.run method or the main method.

Comment: This certainly helps, I somehow ignored the cumulated views... Thanks for the hint! Regarding the back traces: does that mean that 5.8% and 2.8% (based on my numbers) of the created instances are created by the code calling the `Thread.run` method? Or, in other words, do I have to look for the methods along the back trace that change the percentage by a signifant amount (say, jumping from 1% to 4%)?

Comment: No, all of it is created in the hot spot an nothing in the back trace nodes. The hot spot can be invoked with different call stacks and the back traces resolve this information, i.e. the numbers on the back trace nodes only show the part that is contributed along that particular call stack.